# Slow Loading Time (Avg. 2 seconds) after Deploying SvelteKit Project to Netlify

Tags: deployment, server-side-rendering, loading, sveltekit, netlify

I recently deployed a project developed with SvelteKit to Netlify. However, I've been experiencing significant loading times on the website, much slower than anticipated.

To be specific:

The login process takes around 2 seconds.
Retrieving user information also takes approximately 2 seconds.
Other features seem to consistently average around 2 seconds of loading time as well.
I'm trying to pinpoint the root cause: Is it related to my project settings, something with Netlify's configuration, or possibly due to the SSR nature of SvelteKit?

Situation:

1. Developed the project using SvelteKit.
2. Deployed on Netlify.
3. Encountering an average loading time of 2 seconds for most features.

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "build"
```

Any guidance on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated!